# I want to arrange tables horizontally and vertically , contained in two DIVs arranged horizontally

Tags: html, css

I am trying to arrange 8 tables in two rows.I have two divs alligned horizontally
 I am trying to align 
4 tables in rows 1
4 tables in row 2

When I try to put this below  code inside another [left] DIV container. All the tables go in one line. Below is the code that I am using.

```
<div class="datagrid"><table>
    <thead><tr><th>header</th><th>header</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody><tr><td>data</td><td>data</td></tr>
    <tr class="alt"><td>data</td><td>data</td></tr>
    <tr><td>data</td><td>data</td></tr>
    <tr class="alt"><td>data</td><td>data</td></tr>
    <tr><td>data</td><td>data</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    </table></div>
```

Kindly guide me on this issue. If required I can upload complete code that I am using.

Comment: I only see one table here

Comment: same table structure will copied through out the div..

Comment: @khalil try this - http://jsfiddle.net/ecs6z3L0/ or http://jsfiddle.net/112eum5e/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve that by adding a parent container to the first 4 tables and another one to the next 4, like so:

```
<div class="group">
    <div class="datagrid">table 1</div>
    <div class="datagrid">table 2</div>
    <div class="datagrid">table 3</div>
    <div class="datagrid">table 4</div>
</div>
<div class="group">
    <div class="datagrid">table 1</div>
    <div class="datagrid">table 2</div>
    <div class="datagrid">table 3</div>
    <div class="datagrid">table 4</div>
</div>
```

Then, add these style rules:

```
.datagrid {
    float: left;
}

.group {
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Very well given example to solve the solve the problem. It works well.. I have put it iinside my divs and appears in proper format.

Answer (score 0):

Use the float and clear.
Find the Complete code in jsfiddle

[Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bwvqbx34/)

css style

```
    .datagrid{
float:left;
}
.firstRow{
}
.secoudRow{
clear:both;
}
```